# Detect a sentence with specific word between sentences in regex

Tags: php, regex

I wish to remove sentence between sentences that contain the word `visitation` as shown here -> https://regex101.com/r/irAN8r/1

My current regexp is below.

```
[^\r\n\.!]*(?i)visitation*[^\r\n.]+
```

The text to detect is below.

```
`John Doe passed away Wednesday, August 18, 2021. Visitation will be Thursday, August 26, 2021 at ABC Funeral Home. Arrangements are under the direction of McDonald Funeral Home.`
```

The regex does detect the sentence `Visitation will be Thursday, August 26, 2021 at ABC Funeral Home` but it left out the last dot (.) So, when I removed the sentence, I'm left with `two dots` as below...

`John Doe passed away Wednesday, August 18, 2021..Arrangements are under the direction of McDonald Funeral Home.`

But if I use this regexp below...

```
[^\r\n\.!]*(?i)visitation*[^\r\n]+
```

...it will detect the second and third sentence as depicted here -> https://regex101.com/r/m5G7Bk/1

`Visitation will be Thursday, August 26, 2021 at ABC Funeral Home. Arrangements are under the direction of McDonald Funeral Home.`

So, how can I detect the middle sentence only and with the full stop as well?

Comment: Match the dot - `(?i)[^\r\n.!?]*visitation*[^\r\n.!?]+[.!?]?`

Comment: Isbtqba555 It's more efficient if you further use some startpoint [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rzx7Dq/1) (for only searching *between sentences* [demo without `^`](https://regex101.com/r/Rzx7Dq/2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^\r\n.!?]` to match any char but CR, LF and any non-final punctuation, and `[.!?]?` to match the sentence end punctuation:

```
(?i)[^\r\n.!?]*visitation[^\r\n.!?]*[.!?]?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUflNX/3).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `[^\r\n.!?]*` - zero or more chars other than CR, LF, `.`, `!` and `?`
- `visitation` - a substring
- `[^\r\n.!?]*` - zero or more chars other than CR, LF, `.`, `!` and `?`
- `[.!?]?` - an optional `.`, `!` or `?`.